# Ignore Image from size (C#)

Tags: c#

Using IronPDF on Visual Studio 2022 im extracting all image in a pdf file using this code :
`

```
var pdfdoc = IronPdf.PdfDocument.FromFile(pdfselect);

try
            {
                using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = PdfDocument.Open(pdfselect))
                {
                    int imageCount = 1;

                    foreach (Page page in pdfDocument.GetPages())
                    {
                        List<XObjectImage> images = page.GetImages().Cast<XObjectImage>().ToList();
                        foreach (XObjectImage image in images)
                        {
                            byte[] imageRawBytes = image.RawBytes.ToArray();

                            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream($"{pdfselectexport}\\{refzone}\\{numpbo}\\{imageCount}.png", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
                            {
                                writer.Write(imageRawBytes);
                                writer.Flush();
                            }

                            imageCount++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
```

`

How can i make in sort that it ignore automatically certain image with a specific width / height (840x320px) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the dimension of the image and ignore it before saving it to file.

```
foreach (XObjectImage image in images)
      {
        // Check the dimensions of the current image
        if (image.Width == 840 && image.Height == 320)
        {
          // Skip this image and move on to the next one
          continue;
        }

        byte[] imageRawBytes.....
```